# How remove all repos for precise in /etc/apt/sources.list and etc/apt/sources.list.d/ in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade

I am currently upgrading my ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 and they said:
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of

network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is

therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for

repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error:

http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following

signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not

available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5, E:The repository

'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.

So I have to delete precise repos but how do I do that?